# vba referencing another workbook "object does not support this method"

Tags: excel, vba

so pretty simply, I'm trying to compare two columns between two sheets, and if they match, grab a cell and bring it over.

'''
I'm getting "object does not support this method" on the "If wsDest.Cells(iRow, 7) = onhand.wsData.Cells(IrowL, 1) Then" line

so I assume I need to do something else, but with a handful of googling, I can't find any using an if statement in this manner, which is probably the problem but I don't understand why.

snippet of this section of code with comments below

```
Dim onhand As Workbook
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\path_to_the_file\thefile.xls"
Set onhand = Application.Workbooks("thefile.xls")
Set wsData = Worksheets("Datasheet")
Set wsData = Worksheets("destinationsheet")
iRow = 2

For iRow = 2 To 60 ' row 2 to 60 in the source
    IrowL = 2
    For IrowL = 2 To 11 ' row 2 to 11 in the external file
        If wsDest.Cells(iRow, 7) <> "" Then ' if the cell isn't empty
            If wsDest.Cells(iRow, 7) = onhand.wsData.Cells(IrowL, 1) Then ' if the columns match then
                wsDest.Cells(iRow, 9) = onhand.wsData.Cells(IrowL, 17) ' copy the appropriate column to new sheet
                End If
            End If
    Next IrowL
Next iRow
```

Comment: Get rid of the `onhand.`... but previously, change `Set wsData = Worksheets("Datasheet")` to `Set wsData = onhand.Worksheets("Datasheet")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update Worksheet

**Tips**

- Use `Option Explicit` which forces you to declare all variables.
- Use variables for objects: workbook, worksheet, range (not implemented).
- At the beginning of the code, use constants to quickly be able to change their values (only partially implemented).
- Whenever you do stuff in the workbook containing this code, refer to it with `ThisWorkbook`; you don't care what it is named.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub updateData()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const FilePath As String = "C:\path_to_the_file\thefile.xls"
    Const srcName As String = "Datasheet"
    Const destName As String = "destinationsheet"
    
    ' Define Destination Workbook ('dwb').
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook contanining this code.
    ' Define Destination Worksheet ('dest').
    Dim dest As Worksheet
    Set dest = dwb.Worksheets(destName)
    
    ' Define Source Worksbook ('swb')
    Dim swb As Workbook
    Set swb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilePath)
    ' Define Source Worksheet ('src').
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Set src = swb.Worksheets(srcName)
    
    ' Usually people use i, j, k...
    Dim dr As Long ' Destination Row Counter
    Dim sr As Long ' Source Row Counter
    
    ' row 2 to 60 in the source
    For dr = 2 To 60
         ' row 2 to 11 in the external file
         For sr = 2 To 11
             ' if the cell isn't empty
            If dest.Cells(dr, 7) <> "" Then
                 ' if the columns match then
                If dest.Cells(dr, 7).Value = src.Cells(sr, 1).Value Then
                     ' copy the appropriate column to new sheet
                    dest.Cells(dr, 9).Value = src.Cells(sr, 17).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next sr
    Next dr
    
    ' Optionally:
    
    ' IF you're done with Source then close it.
    'swb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' We were only reading.
    ' We were also writing in Destination so save it.
    'dwb.Save

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you are setting two different sheets to `wsData` and you set the workbook at the time of setting the sheet:

```
Dim onhand As Workbook
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\path_to_the_file\thefile.xls"
Set onhand = Application.Workbooks("thefile.xls")
Set wsData = onhand.Worksheets("Datasheet")
Set wsDest= Thisworkbook.Worksheets("destinationsheet")
iRow = 2

For iRow = 2 To 60 ' row 2 to 60 in the source
    For IrowL = 2 To 11 ' row 2 to 11 in the external file
        If wsDest.Cells(iRow, 7) <> "" Then ' if the cell isn't empty
            If wsDest.Cells(iRow, 7) = wsData.Cells(IrowL, 1) Then ' if the columns match then
                wsDest.Cells(iRow, 9) = wsData.Cells(IrowL, 17) ' copy the appropriate column to new sheet
                End If
            End If
    Next IrowL
Next iRow
```

Comment: `IrowL = 2` is redundant/useless too.

Comment: @BigBen yea, but I am not quite sure what the OP actually wants as far as the loop goes.

Comment: Completely agree... the double loop is a red flag.

Comment: @BigBen actually now that I look at it, there are 10 rows on the external file to loop and check against 60 rows in this workbook.  If it matches then bring over.  It is a slow vlookup.

Comment: " and you set the workbook at the time of setting the sheet:"

I dont know what you mean by this

Comment: @Metal a worksheet variable gets the parent workbook at time of being set.  `Set wsData = onhand.Worksheets("Datasheet")` sets the variable with the workbook `onhand`.  Whenyou tried to do `onhand.wsData` it was like saying `ThisWorkbook.Workbooks("thefile.xls").Worksheets("Datasheet")` it does not work.